# How can I use negative window bits with miniz_oxide?

Tags: rust

I want to use window bits like in here.

I tried with `flate2` crate but it only takes u8, but I have to use -15 for my file type. compressed with zlib (-15)

This is my try to use DataFormat for my Decompressor but I don't see any functions to pass DataFormat so far?

```rust
pub fn from_reader<R: Read + Seek>(mut reader: R) -> Result<Self> {
        // Read the entire compressed DocInfo stream into a buffer
        let mut compressed_content = Vec::new();
        reader.read_to_end(&mut compressed_content)?;

        // Decompress the content using miniz_oxide with a negative window bits value
        let mut decompressed_content = Vec::with_capacity(compressed_content.len() * 2);
        let data_format = DataFormat::from_window_bits(-15);
        
        // !! ERROR CODE, i wanna use like this
        // Decompress the content using miniz_oxide with a negative window bits value but only takes one argument
        let data_format = DataFormat::from_window_bits(-15);
        let decompressed_content = decompress_to_vec(&compressed_content, data_format)
            .map_err(|_| std::io::Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, "corrupt deflate stream"))?;


        // Create a cursor to read from the decompressed content
        let mut cursor = std::io::Cursor::new(decompressed_content);
...
```

or I don't know how to start from here.

```rust
let file = File::open("example.abc")?;
let mut compound_file = cfb::CompoundFile::open(file)?;

let header;

// Access the SomeHeaderstream within a block
{
    let mut file_header_stream = compound_file.open_stream("/SomeHeader").unwrap();
    header= FileHeader::from_reader(&mut file_header_stream)?;
}
...
```

Comment: Not sure what's your problem [`from_window_bits`](https://docs.rs/miniz_oxide/0.7.1/miniz_oxide/enum.DataFormat.html#method.from_window_bits) takes an `i32`

Comment: @cafce25 yup that's why I changed from flate2 to oxide, but I cannot find any example of using DataFormat. I tried to use somehow like the first code, but I have no idea to use this value for decompressor?

Comment: You should clearly state **within** your question that using `DataFormat` is your problem, cause otherwise it's confusing. Try to [edit] your post to describe a little where exactly your problem lies, in your first snippet you seem to be using it already, so it's not clear where exactly you struggle.

Comment: From [what I'm reading](https://docs.rs/miniz_oxide/0.7.1/src/miniz_oxide/lib.rs.html#158-163) isn't `-15` the same as `15` but with `zlib_header` set to false in [`Decompress::new`](https://docs.rs/flate2/1.0.25/flate2/struct.Decompress.html#method.new)?

Comment: I know it's werid to use negative value but this file format is compressed with zlib and other implementaions like in JS or python, they set -15 and it works well. `const content = pako.inflate(this.uint_8(FileIndex.content), { windowBits: -15 });` but I'll try false first, thanks!